# Login required decorator is not working properly in the django

Tags: python, django

Login required decorator is not working properly in the django, it will not redirect properly to the login page if user is not registered or logged in.

So in my django framework i made the login page other pages in the project.Now i want say if some other third party user try to run my any webpage on that specific time my website ask him/her for login before accessing my any website page,to resist that i used the login required decorator but when i logged in and copy my other webpage url and paste in the new window it will not show the login page just straight open that webpage in the new window.HOW DO I FIX IT????HELP ME OUT PLEASE.......

URLS OF MY WEBPAGES:-

```
    path("loggedin/",views.loggedin,name="loggedin"),
```

VIEW PAGE:-

```
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
```

This is my index page where user can register his/her self and after that they will login and go to the next page......

```
def index(request):
    return render(request,'userside/index.html')
```

And this is the page which comes after the index(main dashboard) page

```
@login_required(login_url='userside/loggedin')
#@staff_member_required
def mainpage(request):
    return render(request,"userside/mainpage.html")
```

The other webpage of my project

```
@login_required(login_url='/userside/loggedin')
def criminalsinfo(request):
    crimins=Criminals.objects.all()
    return render(request,'userside/criminalsinfo.html',{'crimins':crimins})
```

Comment: hi, by new window, you mean a window of the same browser?

Comment: yes means in the same browser we open a new window

Comment: ok,in same browser means they share same session, instead try opening in incognito or another browser and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yes means in the same browser we open a new window

That means you are already logged in.

To confirm it, in your browser, visit your page and in cookies check if have `sessionid` or not. If yes, then it means you are already logged in.

Possible solutions:

1. Remove `sessionid`.
2. Use `incognito` mode.
3. Use `another browser`.